# How to find the multiplicative inverse of $a+b\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{Q}({\sqrt{2}})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I am struggling with this a lot. I set the product of 2 elements in the field equal to 1 but cannot find a way to write the elements of one element in terms of the other.

Instead of just knowing the answer I’d like to understand how to find it so I can apply this again.

Comment: “Rationalizing denominators”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a method that works in every field of the form $F(r)$, with $r$ of degree $n$ over $F$.

If you are given $t=a_0+a_1r+\dots+a_{n-1}r^n\in F(r)$, $t\ne0$, then you know that the map $u\mapsto tu$ is invertible. Then you can find its matrix with respect to the basis $\{1,r,\dots,r^{n-1}\}$ by taking $t,tr,\dots,tr^{n-1}$ (using the minimal polynomial to reduce higher powers). Find the matrix inverse and you're done, because the inverse is the image of the element $1$, whose coordinate vector is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, so you just take the first column of the matrix.

Example for your case: the minimal polynomial is $x^2-2$; then the elements you need are $(a+b\sqrt{2})1$ and $(a+b\sqrt{2})\sqrt{2}=2b+a\sqrt{2}$. Thus the matrix is
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 2b \\
b & a
\end{bmatrix}
whose inverse is
$$
\frac{1}{a^2-2b^2}\begin{bmatrix} a & -2b \\ -b & a \end{bmatrix}
$$
and the first column will give the required inverse, namely
$$
\frac{a}{a^2-2b^2}-\frac{b}{a^2-2b^2}\sqrt{2}
$$
The same would do for $r=\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $t=a+br+cr^2$. The elements to compute are
$$
a+br+cr^2,\quad (a+br+cr^2)r=2c+ar+br^2,\quad (a+br+cr^2)r^2=2b+2cr+ar^2
$$
so the matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 2c & 2b \\
b & a & 2c \\
c & b & a
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The inverse matrix is
$$
\frac{1}{a^3+2b^3+4c^3-6abc}
\begin{bmatrix}
a^2-2bc & 2b^2-2ac & 4c^2-2ab \\
2c^2-ab & a^2-2bc  & 2b^2-2ac \\
b^2-ac  & 2c^2-ab  & a^2-2bc
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so the inverse is
$$
\frac{a^2-2bc}{a^3+2b^3+4c^3-6abc}+
\frac{2c^2-ab}{a^3+2b^3+4c^3-6abc}\sqrt[3]{2}+
\frac{b^2-ac}{a^3+2b^3+4c^3-6abc}\sqrt[3]{4}
$$
Of course this is easier if you have explicit $a,b,c$.

By the way, this proves that if $t=a+br+cr^2\ne0$, then $a^3+2b^3+4c^3-6abc\ne0$ (this is the norm function).

In the $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ the norm function on $a+b\sqrt{2}$ is $a^2-b^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $(a+b\sqrt{2})(a-b\sqrt{2})=a^2-2b^2$ is non-zero because $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, the inverse is$$\frac{a-b\sqrt{2}}{a^2-2b^2}=\frac{a}{a^2-2b^2}+\frac{-b}{a^2-2b^2}\sqrt{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Set up a system of equations. Say $(a + b \sqrt{2})^{-1} = u + v \sqrt{2}$, multiply and equate:

$\begin{align*}
  (a + b \sqrt{2}) \cdot (u + v \sqrt{2})
    &= (a u + 2 b v) + (a v + b u) \sqrt{2}
\end{align*}$

This gives a system of equations:

$\begin{align*}
  a u + 2 b v
    &= 1 \\
  b u + a v
    &= 0
\end{align*}$

This is a linear system of equations for $u, v$.

Or compute directly, rationalizing:

$\begin{align*}
   \frac{1}{a + b \sqrt{2}}
     &= \frac{a - b \sqrt{2}}{(a - b \sqrt{2}) (a + b \sqrt{2})} \\
     &= \frac{a - b \sqrt{2}}{a^2 - 2 b^2}
\end{align*}$

Unless $a = b = 0$, the denominator is never zero as long as $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different take:

Let $\beta=a+b\sqrt{2}$. Then $\beta^2-2a\beta+a^2-2b^2=0$. Therefore
$
\beta(\beta-2a)=-(a^2-2b^2)
$
and so
$$
\beta\frac{2a-\beta}{a^2-2b^2}=1
$$
Thus, the fraction above is the inverse of $\beta$. (Note that $a^2-2b^2=0$ iff $\beta=0$.)

This approach is systematic and works for every nonzero algebraic number since the independent term in the minimal polynomial is not zero.